# Google Calendar Limit Problem Even Billing was Registered

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I already use Google Calendar API for some months with no problem, but in 28th of August I get an error. The error message is "403 Calendar usage limits exceeded".

Accordingly to Google API Console I didn't reach daily quota limit (I use Service Account).

I was tried to read the official documentation, but everything is okay by my usage.

Here I attach some information from my dashboard.

[image: Dashboard Metrics]
[image: Quotas]
[image: API error response]

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your application doing?  There is a quota limit on the number of calendars you can create in a day that has nothing to do with the daily access quotas.

Comment: My application just use one calendar, only store the events.